# Почему после правильной отработки метода класса возвращается undefined?

Tags: javascript

Есть клас:

```
class Movie {
    constructor(name, category, startShow) {
        this.name = name;
        this.category = category;
        this.startShow = startShow;
    }

    watchMovie() {
        console.log("I watch the movie " + this.name + "!");
    }
}
```

И есть 2 экземпляра класа:

```
const movie1 = new Movie("Titanic", "drama", 1997);
const movie2 = new Movie("Troya", "historical", 2004);

console.log(movie1.watchMovie());
```

Я не понимаю, почему после того, как метод отработал возвращается ещё и undefined
[image: error]

Comment: Потому что нет `return`, да и зачем он там?

Comment: `/*console.log(*/movie1.watchMovie()/*)*/;`

Comment: @Igor это очень красивое решение

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если функция (метод) не возвращает значения явно при помощи `return`, тогда возвращается `undefined`, как и в вашем случае. Вы дважды вызываете `console.log()` — один раз внутри метода со строкой, второй раз вне метода с результатом метода, который и есть `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Потому что он ничего не возвращает, очевидно же...

Answer (score 1):

потому что когда вы вызываете метод, в нем уже прописан console.log, нужно просто написать
movie1.watchMovie();